# Linux redirect standard output to realtime pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I need to understand what the type of queue is that I must use to receive the standard output of a command and not store it (if nobody read on the same queue the contents are immediately lost).

On the same queue I may "attach" another command that read the real time content and use it.

I already view the fifo, but it seems that it stores the content until someone reads it.

Thanks to all

Comment: How would something read it if it was being immediately discarded? What sort of timespan are you considering "immediate"? Do you mean that if there isn't an active listener it should be discarded but that it should be possible for something to say "I'm interested" and get the output until it says "I'm done" or exits/crashes/etc.?

Comment: I try to explain: i would launch a command that receive a rtsp stream that start at system startup and stop at shutdown. When something happend, i would launch a program that get the standard output of a first command and record a video

Comment: The service that is always running does what exactly? Capture the rtsp data? And you want it to throw that away if you haven't attached something that records the stream data to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to work around this issue is by using `tee` as a splitter/buffer. You can create a FIFO using `mkfifo`, then have your program output to this FIFO. When you need to connect an application to the output, create a new FIFO and have `tee` read from the first FIFO and output to the second FIFO. This way, if you need to connect a second app to the output, you can use the second FIFO.

I suppose you could reuse the same FIFO name if you unlink it first. The already running processes will retain a handle on it even if it no longer exists.

```
mkfifo fifo
app > fifo &

mkfifo fifo2
tee fifo2 | rapp1 < fifo &

mkfifo fifo3
tee fifo3 | rapp2 < fifo2 &

# etc.
```

Comment: Note that this will lock up if one of the "receiving" applications quits, as the FIFO will get filled with nobody to read from. Really, if what you need is more complicated than this, you will need to write a proxy application using sockets. Your app will write to a socket and the receiving applications will connect to and read from this socket. This way, the host application is responsible for buffering and can be notified of clients that disconnect from the socket.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, i think that i need to write an application to solve my problem